# What can I do with half-derivative?

Tags: fractional-calculus, translation-request

If I want to know the slope of the tangent of curve function I just have to find the derivative of this function and if I want to know the area under this curve I can integrate it (the function of course) but what can I do with half-derivative ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A problem that fractional derivatives face is that they are terribly non-local, unlike differentiation. There are some ways to come up with intuition but it's not easy. That said, here is the most referenced result on this topic from what I gather: http://people.tuke.sk/igor.podlubny/pspdf/pifcaa_r.pdf.

Comment: See also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153542/geometric-interpretation-of-the-half-derivative

Comment: OK I will try to understand, thank you !

Comment: Try experimenting with $|\zeta^{(n)}(2)|\approx n!~$

Answer (score 1):

From your own question : << If I want to know the slope of the tangent of curve function I just have to find the derivative of this function and if I want to know the area under this curve I can integrate it (the function of course) but what can I do with half-derivative >>, you can expect that fractional derivative will yield to something intermediate between the derivate function and the function itself. But that is notoriously difficult of interpretation.

The bibliography on the subject is extensive. A paper for general public, such as https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire will not give you a sufficient answer. Also, the relationship between fractionnal calculus and fractal geometry is especially to be considered. In an attempt to go further, more specific papers are necessary. For example, among a lot of them :

"Geometric and Physical Interpretation of Fractional Integration and Fractional Differentiation" : http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110241.pdf

"Geometry of fractional spaces": http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.5787.pdf

Comment: Thank you ! Your first link is very useful for me because i'm french so... :D